# Forward Skew using constant smile rule

Tags: implied-volatility, volatility-skew, forward-start

[image: The below pic is from the book "Trading Volatility" by colin bennett]

[image: Excel sheet of my working]

IV1 = IV of far month.

IV2 - IV of near month.

f(1,2) = Forward volatility between the two expiries.

dx = difference between Strike volatility and ATMf volatility of IV2 column.

As per the method given by the author "constant smile rule", does the "Fwd_skew" column in my working represent the 'forward volatility skew' at the given time of the moment.